# Field-specific versioning in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a good deal of documentation about how Elasticsearch supports document level external versioning. However, if one wants to do a partial update (say, to a specific field), it'd be useful to have this type of version checking at the field level.

For instance, say I have an object field `name`, with primitive fields `value` and `timestamp`. I only want the partial updates to succeed if the `timestamp` value is greater than the value currently in Elasticsearch.

Is there an easy way to do this? Can it be done with a script? Or is there a more standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's very easy, using a script. See here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/docs-update.html.

I've written an example here to update the "value" field if and only if the specified timestamp value (given in parameter update_time) is greater than the "timestamp" field. If the timestamp field value is less than the update_time parameter then it will be updated, otherwise the update will not be performed.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "script" : {
    "inline": "if(ctx._source.name.timestamp  > update_time){ ctx.op = \"none\"};   
    ctx._source.name.value = value;  ctx._source.name.timestamp = update_time;", 
    "params" : {
        "update_time" : 432422,
        "value": "My new value"
    }
}
   }'
```

You can get the current time in the script if desired, rather than passing as a parameter e.g.:

```
update_time = DateTime.now().getMillis()
```

Comment: I've edited to fix a bug I had in the update check code.

Comment: Is there a risk here of data loss if another client makes an update in between the time that the timestamp value was checked and the update is made? Or will ES recognize that the update is being made to a different version of the document than what was retrieved? [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html) seems to imply this, but wanted to double check.

Comment: Yes the update will fail if that happened (The update API checks the version numbers match during re-indexing). You could use a sleep(milliseconds) in the script to test this.